# Is there a way to profile non-blocking MPI calls?

Tags: mpi, profiling

I have an application that makes heavy use of three different kinds of non-blocking MPI calls. The requests that are associated with these calls are stored in a single array, which is probed via `MPI_Testsome`.

Profiling indicates that the application spends most of its time sending and receiving data. However, I would really like to be able to find out which type of message the application is spending the most time processing.

I've tried to look into this via DDT, but the profiling data isn't granular enough for me to work this out. In particular, DDT just shows that the application spends most of its time carrying out point-to-point MPI requests, which isn't clear enough for me.

I've considered using `MPI_Wtime` for this: I'm not opposed to this, but I'd like to know if there's a less invasive way to do this sort of profiling before I roll out that approach.

Comment: you can wrap MPI subroutines and add instrumentation. For example, re-implement `MPI_Isend(...)` in order to associate a start time to the request and call the original `PMPI_Isend(...)`. Same thing for `MPI_Testsome(...) and friends: Invoke `PMPI_Testsome(...)` retrieve the start time and compute the elapsed one.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense: looking at this and the accepted answer it seems pretty impossible to do this without some sort of object at global scope, which makes sense. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not trivial, although it is possible.  I don't know any tool that does it, but I can sketch a prototype implementation.

To profile which operations are taking the most time based on the request, you need to associate information with requests.  MPI does not provide a way to do that directly, such as request attributes, so you have to do it another way.

The way to associate information with requests is to create a data structure like a map that has `MPI_Request` as the key and whatever you need to associate with it as the value.  When a nonblocking operation is initiated (e.g. `MPI_Isend`), your interception layer inserts the request, what operation you did, and the start timer into the key-value map.  Then you intercept request completion operations like `MPI_Waitall` and insert the stop time for all completed requests, and do the necessary aggregation of statistics.

https://github.com/jeffhammond/mukautuva/blob/main/impl-keyval-map-ireqa2aw.h is an implementation of this, not for profiling, but allocated memory.  This function is called by https://github.com/jeffhammond/mukautuva/blob/main/impl-keyval-map.cc and then e.g. here https://github.com/jeffhammond/mukautuva/blob/main/impl-wait-functions.c#L407.

An example of operation-specific aggregation of statistics can be found in https://github.com/pmodels/armci-mpi/blob/master/profiler/profiling.c.

Because people on this site don't like code links, here is an untested approximation to the above applied to your use case.

```cpp
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <tuple>

std::map<MPI_Request, 
         std::tuple<std::string, MPI_Aint, double>
        > profiling{};

int MPI_Isend(const void *buf, int count, MPI_Datatype datatype,
              int dest, int tag, MPI_Comm comm, MPI_Request *request)
{
    double t0 = MPI_Wtime();
    int rc = IMPL_Isend(buf, count, datatype, dest, tag, comm, 
                        &request);
    MPI_Aint bytes = MPI_Type_size(datatype);
    bytes *= count;
    auto stuff = std::make_tuple("ISEND", bytes, t0);
    profiling.insert_or_assign(request, stuff);
    return rc;
}

int MPI_Wait(MPI_Request * request, MPI_Status * status)
{
    rc = MPI_Wait(request, status);
    t1 = MPI_Wtime();
    auto [name,bytes,t0] = profiling.at(request);
    auto dt = t1 - t0;
    std::cout << name << " took " << dt << " seconds to send " 
              << bytes << " bytes\n";
    profiling.erase(request);
    return rc;
}
```

I didn't test this code but it's based on the linked code that has been proven to work in a similar context.  I guess I should use `extract` instead of `at` and `erase` but I haven't used that method before; I'll fix the example once I test it.

I created https://github.com/jeffhammond/plumber/issues/5 since this is a neat feature and it would be great to have a proper implementation.  I don't know when I'll have time to work on this, but you are welcome to pester me via that GitHub issue if it would make a difference for me to implement this.